# Conditionally Update Stage Name

Tags: apex, batch

We need to check the condition like Opportunity IsClosed field is set to true, before determining whether or not the it’s been closed less than 30/45 days from when it was created.

As of now my current logic is doing closed less than 30/45 days the stages are not changed it same as when deal is true. Now we are looking in to when `Deal = true` when 0/45 days from when the Opportunity was created along with `isClosed = true` and `Stage = 'closed won'`.

Current logic:

```
if(opp.Deal__c!=true)
{
    if(mp_ListOpportunityOrderSplit.get(opp.id)!=null)
    {
        for(Opportunity_Splits__c oppOrderSplitRecd : mp_ListOpportunityOrderSplit.get(opp.id))
        {
            if(oppOrderSplitRecd.Account__c!=null && ((oppOrderSplitRecd.Account__r.name.containsIgnoreCase('GE Intelligent platforms')&& date.valueOf(opp.createdDate).daysBetween(date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate))<=30)|| (!oppOrderSplitRecd.Account__r.name.containsIgnoreCase('  platforms')&& date.valueOf(opp.createdDate).daysBetween(opp.CloseDate)<=45)))
            {
                opp.Deal__c = true;
                opp.Qualifying_Criteria__c='Closed less than 45 days from opportunity creation';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        //for(Opportunity_Splits__c oppOrderSplitRecd : mp_ListOpportunityOrderSplit.get(opp.id))
        if(date.valueOf(opp.createdDate).daysBetween(date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate))<=30)
        {
            opp.Deal__c = true;
            opp.Qualifying_Criteria__c='Closed less than 30 days from opporunity creation';
            //break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit briefly what are you are expecting

Comment: @pavan tej, Thanks for your reply.Actually am expecting When this criteria is met "Closed less than 30 /45 days from opportunity creation"  then deal =true. which is working fine problem is we need to change the stage = 'closed' when criteria met = 'Closed less than 30 /45 days from opportunity creation'and is changed field should be checked.     Please help me on this Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to break out your logic a little so that you can follow it (and debug it more easily.

I've modified your code and added in the conditions that (I think) you want. It's not entirely clear however, so this is my best guess:

```
if(opp.Deal__c!=true)
{
    Integer oppAge = Date.valueOf(opp.createdDate).daysBetween(Date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate));
    Boolean oppClosed = (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' && opp.IsClosed == true) ? true : false;

    if(mp_ListOpportunityOrderSplit.get(opp.id)!=null)
    {
        for(Opportunity_Splits__c oppOrderSplitRecd : mp_ListOpportunityOrderSplit.get(opp.id))
        {
            if(oppOrderSplitRecd.Account__c == null && !oppClosed ){
                continue;
            }

            if( (oppOrderSplitRecd.Account__r.Name.containsIgnoreCase('GE Intelligent platforms') && oppAge<=30) || 
                (!oppOrderSplitRecd.Account__r.Name.containsIgnoreCase('  platforms') && oppAge<=45))
            {
                opp.Deal__c = true;
                opp.Qualifying_Criteria__c='Closed less than 45 days from opportunity creation';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (oppAge <= 30 && oppClosed) {
       opp.Deal__c = true;
       opp.Qualifying_Criteria__c='Closed less than 30 days from opporunity creation';
       //break;
    }
}
```